# Spring Tool Suite publishing bower_components and node_modules

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-wtp

There are other posts here on this which I have tried to follow but still desired effect not achieved. When doing AngularJS on a java project in the webapp folder, grunt and the angularjs build process creates node_modules and bower_components to build the app. Then when running/debugging the Java web app, WTP publishes contents of webapp to the destination of the server to find it. The trouble is node_modules and the bower_components are like 200M and naturally slow the process down. Designating in the Java Scripts Include Path in the project properties to ignore these directions doesn't exclude them from being published. 

File layout:
[image]

the settings that don't work.

[image]

Comment: not sure this helps in this exact setting, but did you take a look at the "Deployment Assembly" settings in your project properties section? I think there should be a way to exclude things from being copied over. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Martin, I've played around with the deployment assembly. Once you include the webapp/ I believe you get everything in it. Don't think there is an exclude option. Actually the deployment assembly I don't think is working correctly either. The web project has dependency on a core project where services and dao's live. WTP won't deploy either the jar or any classes from that project. I package the jar at the cmd line then drag in explorer to the server dir. I included the project in the deployment assembly and it ignores it. Can't include image of that settings in a comment. Darn.

Answer (score 0):

Take your package.json, bower.json and Gruntfile.js out of webapp to the project root. Have your JS, CSS, HTML code in the app folder under the project root. Modify the Gruntfile.js such that when it builds your web staff (downloads dependencies, concatenates JS and CSS) it copies the results of the build JS, CSS, HTML into the webapp folder (A grunt copy task - example below, but should be plenty available online).

```
    my: {
  app: 'app',
  dist:          '../src/main/webapp'
},


    copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= my.app %>',
        dest: '<%= my.dist %>',
        src: [
          '*.{ico,png,txt}',
          '*.html',
          'views/{,*/}*.html',
          'lib/**/*',
          'scripts/**/*',
          'fonts/*',
          'images/**/*'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= my.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  },
},
```